# What is a "color film copy transparency"?

Tags: film, scanning, digitizing

Library of Congress usually has different versions of digitized works. [see this example](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/93515921/)

What is "color film copy transparency"? and what is its different with "digital file from original"?

Comment: Pretty sure this is off topic for photograpy.  It's a good question, but I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site it would fit on exactly.

Comment: History might be the best place to ask this.  Perhaps a mod can see about migrating it there.

Comment: Hmm... @AJHenderson history of photography, photography in society, techniques (preservation would fit I think), are all on topic here. I think it's ok.

Comment: JoanneC: but it isn't history of photography.  It's a painting.

Comment: Your answer, however, includes photography. I think it may be close to the edge, but it's kind of refreshing to have some history/preservation here. We do, after all, have questions on taking photos of art. So, why not how to handle those photos after?

Comment: I suppose if it was reworked to focus on how photography is used in art preservation it could be on topic though digital file from original may be photo or scan so it still feels like an art history question rather than photo.

Comment: Also agree about it being borderline (hence why I still answered it.)

Comment: I don't think we need to be too concerned about whether a question is on-topic if there is a way to make it obviously fit. The ability to provide a solid, photography-related answer is really what matters. One way or another, whether the question involved a painting or not, the ANSWER here is **valuable to other photographers.** If someone searches "color film copy transparency" on google, and ends up here, well, they won't be left wondering at the answer to their question! :)

Comment: The only time I think we should really concern ourselves about whether a question is off-topic is when it simply can't be answered in a photographic context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For color film copy transparency, they took a color photograph (negative), developed a color transparency (positive) and scanned the transparency to produce a digital file.  Digital file from original means that the original was either scanned or digitally photographed.  It has to do with what was digitized, was it the original or some kind of copy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know why they do make those negatives and positives while they can easily scan the originals with their medium format cameras?

Comment: @Omne - if I had to guess, probably just time.  It's a lot easier to do a high quality scan of the film you have on file than it is to pull an artifact from display and do another detailed capture of it.  They may update it eventually, but it's far quicker to scan a bunch of archival stuff than it is to pull thousands of artifacts off display.